# Wired connection doesn't connect after suspending PC and starting it back in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, internet, suspend, ethernet, wired

Wired connection doesn't connect after suspending PC and starting it back. The system is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Output of `lspci` command:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 590f (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5902 (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
```

And output of `lspci -k | grep -iA3 ethernet` (I don't know what does this command show but I have come across this command when I was looking for the answer in google) command:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard (one of many)
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169`
```

Edit on Sep 9 2017, Sat:
I tried to install r8168 driver from realtek's site. First, I followed the manual instructions in this site: https://unixblogger.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/

I tried to install dependencies by entering the code into terminal:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

and then I downloaded the driver from Realtek's site: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2

I downloaded the version which states Linux driver for kernel up to 4.7. I don't exactly if that is the case, if that one is causing me the problems.

Then I blacklisted my already installed and working r8169 driver by this code:

```
user@linux:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo blacklist r8169 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'
```

Then I untarred the archive by this code: `tar xfvj 0009-r8168-8.044.02.tar.bz2`

which showed me the following output:

```
r8168-8.044.02/
r8168-8.044.02/autorun.sh
r8168-8.044.02/Makefile
r8168-8.044.02/README
r8168-8.044.02/src/
r8168-8.044.02/src/Makefile
r8168-8.044.02/src/Makefile_linux24x
r8168-8.044.02/src/r8168.h
r8168-8.044.02/src/r8168_asf.c
r8168-8.044.02/src/r8168_asf.h
r8168-8.044.02/src/r8168_dash.h
r8168-8.044.02/src/r8168_fiber.h
r8168-8.044.02/src/r8168_n.c
r8168-8.044.02/src/r8168_realwow.h
r8168-8.044.02/src/rtltool.c
r8168-8.044.02/src/rtltool.h
r8168-8.044.02/src/rtl_eeprom.c
r8168-8.044.02/src/rtl_eeprom.h
```

After that I got into that folder `r8168-8.044.02/` and compiled the script autorun.sh `sudo ./autorun.sh`which showed me the following output on terminal:

```
Check old driver and unload it.
rmmod r8169
Build the module and install
At main.c:158:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
Backup r8169.ko
rename r8169.ko to r8169.bak
DEPMOD 4.10.0-33-generic
load module r8168
Updating initramfs. Please wait.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-33-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
Completed.
```

Then I run this code: `lsmod | grep r8168` which output: `r8168                 499712  0`

Then I run `sudo ethtool -i enp2s0`.

After that I suspended my PC and reopened it back, but it had the same problem, it did not connect to Wired connection after suspension. I had reboot it to get working Ethernet connection. After rebooting I tried to install it automatically rather than manually, so I edited `/etc/apt/sources.list`, I changed `xenial main restricted` to `xenial main restricted universe`. Then I `sudo apt-get update`, then I `sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms`. However, those things also did not help, when I suspended my PC. So, I had to reboot again to get internet connection.

After rebooting I followed some of the instructions in this site: https://nosemaj.org/hardy-r8168.

I run:

```
sudo bash
```

then `rmmod r8169` which output `rmmod: ERROR: Module r8169 is not currently loaded`.

then `make clean` which output:

```
make -C src/ clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/garakchy/my_stuff_002/drivers_I_downloaded/r8168-8.044.02/src'
make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-33-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/garakchy/my_stuff_002/drivers_I_downloaded/r8168-8.044.02/src clean
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic'
  CLEAN   /home/garakchy/my_stuff_002/drivers_I_downloaded/r8168-8.044.02/src/.tmp_versions
rm: cannot remove '/home/garakchy/my_stuff_002/drivers_I_downloaded/r8168-8.044.02/src/.tmp_versions/r8168.mod': Permission denied
Makefile:1569: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make[2]: *** [clean] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic'
Makefile:99: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make[1]: *** [clean] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/garakchy/my_stuff_002/drivers_I_downloaded/r8168-8.044.02/src'
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

then `make modules` which output:

```
make -C src/ modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/garakchy/my_stuff_002/drivers_I_downloaded/r8168-8.044.02/src'
make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-33-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/garakchy/my_stuff_002/drivers_I_downloaded/r8168-8.044.02/src modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic'
rm: cannot remove '/home/garakchy/my_stuff_002/drivers_I_downloaded/r8168-8.044.02/src/.tmp_versions/r8168.mod': Permission denied
Makefile:1511: recipe for target 'crmodverdir' failed
make[2]: *** [crmodverdir] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic'
Makefile:95: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/garakchy/my_stuff_002/drivers_I_downloaded/r8168-8.044.02/src'
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

then `make install` etc. After all, I suspended my PC and reopened it back, it totally crashed and stopped working at all, let alone the not working Ethernet connection. My PC got stuck. I reboot. After rebooting my PC temporarily working in good condition, but I wanted to go back to r8169 driver, which was installed default. So, I changed `modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, I deleted r8169 there and wrote r8168 instead.

Output of `sudo lshw -class network` command:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 02
       serial: d0:50:99:72:eb:0c
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.044.02-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.26 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0010000-d0010fff memory:d0000000-d000ffff memory:90000000-9000ffff
```

It shows r8168 as a driver still, even if I had blacklisted it.

Here are some other information that I thought would be useful: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25497742/

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 09 Sep 2017 16:58 +03 +0300

Booted last: 09 Sep 2017 00:00 +03 +0300

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.10.0-33-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 14:07:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard (one of many) [1849:8168]
    Kernel driver in use: r8168

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

mxm_wmi                16384  0
wmi                    16384  1 mxm_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.26  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9d89:9a06:9c3c:aa5f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:841359 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:508522 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1206038659 (1.2 GB)  TX bytes:39262133 (39.2 MB)
          Interrupt:17 Base address:0xd000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3258 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3258 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:329425 (329.4 KB)  TX bytes:329425 (329.4 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       826     1  0 15:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Motherboard (one of many))
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8168
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 8.044.02-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       10942507-8479-3f0f-aa05-39f5cfc92e15
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   10942507-8479-3f0f-aa05-39f5cfc92e15 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.26/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          home
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       expiry = 1505045259
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.26
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = home
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 75600
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::9d89:9a06:9c3c:aa5f/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Istanbul (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp2s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist r8168

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   27.284525] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   27.284681] enp2s0: 0xffff9b47c0c8d000, <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>, IRQ 17
[   27.312137] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   30.374732] r8168: enp2s0: link up
[   30.374745] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

I don't know what to do. Can you help me please? Thanks